# Why does command prompt give me an error code in compilation when my IDE doesn't?

Tags: java

Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I'm new to programming in general. Recently, I decided to try and make some sort of CYOA game through Java as a challenge to myself. It ran perfectly fine on the IDE (Eclipse) but when I tried to use the java and javac command in command prompt for my Main.java file, it didn't work.

```
Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                game.MainCharacter mc = new game.MainCharacter();
                    ^
  symbol:   class MainCharacter
  location: package game
Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                game.MainCharacter mc = new game.MainCharacter();
                                                ^
  symbol:   class MainCharacter
  location: package game
2 errors
```

is the error that pops up. On my IDE however, nothing of the sort pops up, letting me run the code with no problems whatsoever. It just happens in command line. Am I missing something?

```java
package game;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose your class:");
        System.out.println("Soldier\nMage\nTechnician");
        String choice = "null";
        game.MainCharacter mc = new game.MainCharacter();
        do {
            choice = input.nextLine();
            try {
                mc.changeClass(choice);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                input.next();
            }
            if (mc.job != null) {
                i++;
            }
        } while (i < 1); i--;
        System.out.format("You've picked %s. Now please, tell me what I should call you.%n",mc.job);
        String name = input.next();
        mc.setName(name);
        mc.showStats();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

---

```java
package game;

public class MainCharacter {
    protected int physical;
    protected int magical;
    protected int technical;
    protected String name;
    protected String job;
    
    public void changeClass(String kw) {
        switch (kw.toLowerCase()) {
        case "soldier":
            this.Soldier();
            break;
        case "mage":
            this.Mage();
            break;
        case "technician":
            this.Technician();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }
    }
        
    public void showStats() {
        System.out.format("%s, the %s\nPhysical: %d\nMagical: %d\nTechnical: %d%n",
                      this.name,this.job,this.physical,this.magical,this.technical);
        }
        
    public void setName(String change) {
        this.name = change;
    }
    
    public void Soldier() {
        this.physical = 6;
        this.magical = 3;
        this.technical = 1;
        this.job = "Soldier";
    }
    
    public void Mage() {
        this.physical = 1;
        this.magical = 7;
        this.technical = 2;
        this.job = "Mage";
    }
    
    public void Technician() {
        this.physical = 1;
        this.magical = 2;
        this.technical = 7;
        this.job = "Technician";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `javac` command look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to compile this stuff, by hand, on the command line (don't do that - use a build system like maven):

Ensure you have a 'source root' directory. This is some dir on your system, say, `/Users/emit/workspace/mygame`, such that `cd game; cat MainCharacter.java` would work (as in, subdirs for packages, then the source file).

Compile by listing **each and every source file explicitly by hand** as argument to `javac` (told you you want a build system), whilst you are in the source root. so:

```
cd /Users/emit/workspace/mygame
javac -cp ../lib/dep1.jar:../lib/dep2.jar game/Main.java game/MainCharacter.java
```

where 'dep1' and 'dep2' are third party libraries you are using (if you have none, then you don't need the `-cp` or the rest of that.

Then, to run it, be in that directory and run:

```
java -cp .:../lib/dep1.jar:../lib/dep2.jar game.Main
```

Note the `-cp .` part, that's important (just stick with `-cp .` if you have no dependencies).

Comment: Ahh! Okay. Thank you! This sheds more light on it.